# Range of unicode characters GHC accepts

Tags: string, haskell, unicode, ghc

This may sound a bit ridiculous, but GHC fails to compile my string containing bacon, a croissant, cucumber, and a potato:

```
main = putStrLn "      "
```

I realize I could easily write

```
main = putStrLn "\x1F953  \x1F950  \x1F952  \x1F954"
```

to the same effect, but I had always assumed GHC would accept any unicode in its source. So: **what are the actual restrictions on unicode characters GHC accepts in source files**?

---

BTW: I realize that supporting this sort of thing is hell for the GHC lexer (actually I ran across the above problem while writing test cases for a lexer I wrote), but I still am a tad bit disappointed.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In general GHC needs to know the Unicode character categories of characters in its input (to decide what is a normal identifier vs. an operator, etc.), so I'd guess the answer is whatever characters are defined in the Unicode database when GHC was built. It looks like GHC only allows printable characters in string literals, and it doesn't know whether your made-up characters are printable.

Comment: What is the platform? What is the encoding of the input file?

Comment: @ReidBarton I thought Unicode was specifically designed to prevent this issue. I mean, one should be able to decode, say, utf8 into Unicode codepoints without caring about what those are. Between quotes, and with the usual escaping rules, I believe GHC should not care about what category the codepoints belong to. If it does error on valid unicode between quotes, that looks as a bug to me.

Comment: I think GHC is actually rather more permissive than what the Report says it should accept in string literals. (The lexical syntax bottoms out in things like "any Unicode lowercase letter", "any Unicode symbol or punctuation", etc. Never "any Unicode character".)

Comment: Weird, I can't even _copy those strings to my terminal_! (xfce4-terminal 0.6.3) In IHaskell I get the same error as mb21 below.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I thought the same thing, but it turned out I just can't copy them to GHCi... Using iTerm on macOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Saving `main = putStrLn "      "` as UTF-8 and running it with `ghc 8.0.1` on macOS, I got:

```
lexical error in string/character literal at character '\129365'
```

I found this related (but closed) [ghc bug report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5518):

> The cause (for both problems) was that older versions of GHC support a older version of Unicode:
>
> ```
> $ ghc-7.0.3 -e "Data.Char.generalCategory '\8342'"
> NotAssigned
> ```

So the problem seems to be that the version of ghc we're using doesn't support the newer emojis yet – it thinks the unicode code point is unassigned and errors out even though it's assigned to the emoji in newer versions of unicode.

A related [open ghc bug ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8524) which mostly discusses which whitespace chars are allowed though.

Finally, the [`lit_error` function in `Lexer.x`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x#L1685) seems to be where the error is surfaced. There are multiple functions in that file that call that error though, so not sure where it's coming from exactly...

Comment: I think it comes from here https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x#L1495 -- `isAny` checks whether the character is printable.

Comment: @ReidBarton Am I reading [this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/876b00ba25a615423f48b0cf9d443a9fd5dbd6f4/libraries/base/cbits/WCsubst.c) right? Does GHC have an array of all the characters it supports!?

Comment: @Alec yes, this is how functions like `isPrint` are implemented. The table is generated automatically from files from the Unicode standard.

Comment: @ReidBarton. Thanks a lot!